# What does LinearModelFit depend on except for its arguments?

Tags: bugs, fitting

I thought this would be always true, but most likely it returns false.

```
random = {RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {500, 5}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 500]};
SameQ @@ Table[LinearModelFit[random], {100}]
(*False*)
```

How is this explained?

Comment: your code returns true on Mathematica version 9 on macos

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem the user claims to be experiencing can not be reproduced.

Comment: @chris FWIW, I get around 50% `False` for multiple evaluation on 9.01 on Windows.

Comment: so it seems to be an OS dependent problem/bug?

Comment: I can reproduce this problem. Please don't close this question

Comment: @chris it looks like it. See the link at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

Update: This seems to be a problem restricted to 32 bits Windows systems

---

Just copying your first line

```
random = {RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {500, 5}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 500]};
```

and then a slight change:

```
mods = Tally@Table[LinearModelFit[random], {1000}]
```

I tally the resulting `FittedModel`s. I sometimes get only a single model (counted 1000 times) and sometimes two models (each about 500 times).

When I get two models, they never differ in the fitted parameter values, but in a different aspect. The following line checks all model properties for differences.

```
Select[LinearModelFit[random]["Properties"], mods[[1, 1]][#] != mods[[2, 1]][#] &] // Quiet
```

> {"MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervals", 
>   "MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervalTableEntries", "PredictedResponse", 
>   "SinglePredictionConfidenceIntervalTableEntries"}

The differences in these are always very small, a typical example:

```
mods[[1, 1]]["MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervals"] - 
mods[[2, 1]]["MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervals"] // Flatten // Union
```

> {-1.11022*10^-16, -5.55112*10^-17, -4.16334*10^-17, \
>   -2.77556*10^-17, -2.08167*10^-17, -1.38778*10^-17, -6.93889*10^-18, \
>   -3.46945*10^-18, 0., 3.46945*10^-18, 6.93889*10^-18, 1.38778*10^-17, 
>    2.08167*10^-17, 2.77556*10^-17, 5.55112*10^-17}

This looks like a very small rounding error though it is strange that it occurs at random. Originally I thought the confidence intervals might be found using bootstrapping, which involves randomness, but the amount of randomness here seems to small for that. [This Mathgroup thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/7wFdzLW-9KU/kWSJbCldZlwJ), pointing in the direction of Intel's Math-Kernel-Library (MKL) may be related.